# Is there a way to block the main thread until a swingworker is done?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I wait for a SwingWorker's doInBackground() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261666/how-do-i-wait-for-a-swingworkers-doinbackground-method)

I've read that its really bad practice to do this but I think its the best way for me to achieve my goal...
Is there a way to block the main thread until the swing worker has finished in the following example?

```
public void flashNode(Node node, int noOfFlashes) {
    GraphUpdater updater = new GraphUpdater(node, noOfFlashes);
    updater.execute();
}
```

and the `SwingWorker` class

```
    public class GraphUpdater extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {
    Node node;
    int noOfFlashes;

    public GraphUpdater(Node n, int noFlashes) {
        node = n;
        noOfFlashes = noFlashes;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Color origColor = node.getColor();
        for (int i=0; i<noOfFlashes; i++) {
            changeNodeColor(node, Color.WHITE);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            changeNodeColor(node, origColor);
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }

        return 1;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261666/how-do-i-wait-for-a-swingworkers-doinbackground-method

Comment: But why do you use a Swingworker if you want to block the main UI thread in the first place? You could just run the code in the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as I mentioned, never use `Thread#sleep(int)` during Swing EDT, GUI simple freeze until `Thread#sleep(int)` ends, more in the [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), example about freeze [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7944388/714968)

you have three (maybe four) options how to update GUI on some period or to delay per time some execution(s)

- use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- use [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html)
- use `Runnable#Thread`

put all together [here](http://tp://stackoverflow.com/q/7049095/714968) (plus `java.util.Timer` with executions wrapped into `invokeLater`)

Comment: thanks for that. using a swing timer can i force it to only exit the method after the timer as stopped running?

Comment: @Josh I think that yes, but (sorry for that) as I see your thread, please post your idea/question about Timer translated to the Java code, then most of readers can answering ...., just edit your question and add new code, based for example javax.swing.Timer with SwingWorker http://stackoverflow.com/q/6186188/714968

Answer (score 1):

If you want to block, then don't use a swing worker, just do

```
changeNodeColor(node, Color.WHITE);
Thread.sleep(500);
changeNodeColor(node, origColor);
Thread.sleep(500);
```

on the EDT. SwingWorker's whole purpose is to *not* block the EDT.

If you just want to change the color of a component at certain intervals (i.e. flash the component) then a `javax.swing.Timer` might be more appropriate.

Comment: I forgot to notice your answer, never really, never to suggest block EDT as an answer for newbee, this way could be road to the hell without deepest knowledges about Swing's EDT, please remove these words and code