# After clicking a button, how do I wait for SwingWorker to finish before proceeding?

Tags: join, swingworker

I have the following code:

```
public class FileLoader extends SwingWorker(Void, Void) {
    @Override
    private Void doInBackground() {
        loadFiles();
    }
}

public class LogInPage {

    private FileLoader fileLoader = new FileLoader();

    public LogInPage() {
        fileLoader.execute();
    }

    loginButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //wait for files to finish loading
        //while displaying a waiting cursor

        showMainForm();
    }
}
```

My question would be:

After clicking the button, I would want all the files to be loaded first (while displaying an hourglass cursor and progress bar) before showing the main form.

I have done this before with Thread's join() but was not able to do the same  with SwingWorker.

I have read about overriding done() and implementing listeners but I can't apply it here.

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying and contrary to what you think, I think you can actually use SwingWorker's done() method.  Before execute(), disable the button, start a busy animation, whatever, then in the done() method, do whatever it is you need to do to continue the program.  That's what it's for :-)

You should also look at the SwingWorker.publish() and process() to send and receive the progress bar events.

See also: [How do I wait for a SwingWorker's doInBackground() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261666/how-do-i-wait-for-a-swingworkers-doinbackground-method)