# Missing return value on Void method?

Tags: java, generics

The following code gives me compile-time errors: missing return value and missing return statement, what value would I return for this *`Void Type`*?

```
final SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // some code
        if (something) {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use return null. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643906/uses-for-the-java-void-reference-type

Comment: I cant use Void in lowercase because of generics

Comment: @HericDenis: Then you should understand that you *do* need to return something (probably a null reference)... it's not just a normal void method with no return value.

Comment: I will return null, but I was like: maybe some nullPointerException will happen idk, this is crazy

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`Void` is not `void`, change it to void type if you don't want to return anything.

Void is a class, void is type.

```
/**
 * The {@code Void} class is an uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a
 * reference to the {@code Class} object representing the Java keyword
 * void.
 *
 * @author  unascribed
 * @since   JDK1.1
 */
```

If you want `Void`, then you need to add `return` statement at end.

Example:

```
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    // some code
    if (something) {
       return null;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but I was not sure it was going to give some NullPointerException or something. Thanks

Comment: @HericDenis: I don't think it fails. See this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261666/how-do-i-wait-for-a-swingworkers-doinbackground-method

Comment: there is a null missing after the first return statement

Comment: Yeah, it seems like :) Thanks @Nambari

Answer (score 1):

Check this. It asks to return `Void` with captital "V" not with simple `void`

```
final SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // my code here
        return null;
    }
}
```